# JQUERY .each function - Create new string for later use

Tags: jquery, csv

I'm trying to find a way to write a string every time a".each" loop is run, so I can append this data to a CSV file.

the code I am using so far is

```
$(xml).find('room').each(function () {
   var roomCode = $(this).attr('roomCode');
   var From = $(this).find("stay").attr("from");
   var To = $(this).find("stay").attr("to");
   var unquieID = $(this).attr('uniqueId');

                 // more variables

   $('.xmlData').append("<p>" "In use from: " + From + "</p>");
   $('.xmlData').append("<p>" "Till " + To + "</p>");
   $('.xmlData').append("<p>" "roomCode" + "<Strong>" + roomCode + "</strong>" + "</p>");
                 });

                 //some more code

$('.btn-success').click(function () {
  var CSV = [
             '"","Title1","Title2","Title2"',
             '"","' + varFromAnotherEACHFunction1 + '","' + var2FromAnotherEACHFunction + '","' + var3FromAnotherEACHFunction + '"',
                 ].join('\n');

                 //some more code

var csvFile = new Blob([CSV], { type: contentType });
```

What i've been trying to do it add

```
StringData = [roomCode, From, To, UniqueID].join;
```

After the `$('.xmlData').append("<p>" "roomCode"` line (StringData declared previously), and change the "blob" line to read `var csvFile = new Blob([CSV, StringData], { type: contentType });`

..but that isn't giving me

> function join() { [native code] }

instead of

001 (in one cell) , 01/08 (in the next), 02/08,   then (as it goes round the function again,  002, 02/06 , 03/06

etc

could some please help? I could see lots of "using a string with a .each function", but nothing for "create a different string each time you go though a .each function".
thanks

Comment: join is a method, like you are using it with the `.join('\n')` in your logic.

Comment: When you get `function xx() { [native code] }` (or when it shows the function code) it means you are referring to the function itself and not calling that function.  Add `()` to call(invoke) the function, possible with parameters eg `.join(',')`

Comment: You need to actually call join()--with the brackets--right now it's just giving you the implementation of the join function. Also you have a typo in your uniqueId variable (and you've capitalised it in your array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Join` is a function and needs to be passed the separator as an argument. I think what you're trying to do is this:

```js
var roomCode = "ABC123";
var From = "2017-01-01";
var To = "2017-08-04";
var UniqueID = 1234567890;
var StringData = [roomCode, From, To, UniqueID].join(",");

console.log(StringData);
```

Comment: Hi Jamiec, This does the job great, thank, ..but.... the output of ar csvFile = new Blob([CSV, (StringData)], { type: contentType }); only gives me the last iteration (and I know it goes round four times). IS there a way to get the first 3 interations also ?

Comment: var StringData = StringData + [roomCode, From, To, UniqueID].join(",");   get me close , but it adds [object Object] to the being of the string.

Comment: HI, You anyone else looking for an answer, and for my future self, I managed to get round this by inserting the line `AllRmString = StringData.slice(15);` , then using the the `AllRmString` var. Prob a big "no no" but it works. Thank you everyone that helped